# Knockout.js Update ViewModel on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

Well, that's not the best situation description... Anyway, I'm trying to update my ViewModel but it's not working. By default I'm getting data from controller function and by button click - from another function in same contoller, but ViewModel contain only data received after first ViewModel initialization.

```
<script>
     function viewModel () {
        var self = this;
        self.currentPage = ko.observable();
        self.pageSize = ko.observable(10);
        self.currentPageIndex = ko.observable(0);
        self.salesdata = ko.observableArray();
        self.newdata = ko.observable();
        self.currentPage = ko.computed(function () {
            var pagesize = parseInt(self.pageSize(), 10),
            startIndex = pagesize * self.currentPageIndex(),
            endIndex = startIndex + pagesize;
            return self.salesdata.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
        });
        self.nextPage = function () {
            if (((self.currentPageIndex() + 1) * self.pageSize()) < self.salesdata().length) {
                self.currentPageIndex(self.currentPageIndex() + 1);
            }
            else {
                self.currentPageIndex(0);
            }
        }
        self.previousPage = function () {
            if (self.currentPageIndex() > 0) {
                self.currentPageIndex(self.currentPageIndex() - 1);
            }
            else {
                self.currentPageIndex((Math.ceil(self.salesdata().length / self.pageSize())) - 1);
            }
        }
        //Here I'm trying to update ViewModel
        self.request = function (uri) {
            $.ajax({
                url: uri,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: [],
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data.$values, {}, self.salesdata);
            }
            });
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/sales",
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
        }).done(function (data) {
            var vm = new viewModel();
            vm.salesdata(data.$values);
            ko.applyBindings(vm);
        }).error(function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        });
        //Here i'm calling for ViewModel update
        $(".btn-default").click(function () {
            days = $(this).val();
            var uri = "/api/sales?days=" + days;     
            new viewModel().request(uri);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE.**
I chaged block of code where I'm getting new data to be as follow:

```
self.request = function (uri) {
                $.getJSON(uri, function (data) {
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.$values, {}, viewModel);
                });
            }
```

Unfortunately this is not working as well. Here is no any JS errors, controller return proper portion of updated data.

Comment: are you sure that there is no JavaScript error and your request invokes success handler?

Comment: After some investigation I suppose that problem in this line - ko.mapping.fromJS(data.$values, {}, viewModel); because when I try to show data via alert (data.$values) it's showing Object instead of data. And yes, in order to avoid calling viewmodel again I used clickeevnt as @GoTo suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Final solution based on @GoTo answer is:
**Here is the way to call function in viewmodel via click databind.**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="7" value="7" data-bind="click: getDays.bind($data, '7')">7</button>
```

**Here is the function.** As you can see I'm calling *self.salesdata* instead of *viewModel*. This solution is working fine but somehow now I have problem with data format that is binded this way - 
`<td data-bind="text: moment($data.whensold).format('DD.MM', 'ru')"></td>`.

```
 self.getDays = function (days) {
                    var uri = "/api/sales?days=" + days;
                    $.getJSON(uri, function (data) {
                        ko.mapping.fromJS(data.$values, {}, self.salesdata);
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Which answer should I give bounty? @brader24 same as Goto both gave an idea for solution.

Answer (score 6):

I'm new to all of this, but if I'm reading your code correctly, you are calling the request function on a new instance of the view model and not the one that was bound to the html document.  You need to make the request call on the view model that you created after the initial get call completed.

Update:
Sorry, I should have been more specific about the code I was referring to.  At the end of your code block you have the following code:

```
    $(".btn-default").click(function () {
        days = $(this).val();
        var uri = "/api/sales?days=" + days;     
        new viewModel().request(uri);
    });
```

In this code, it appears that each time the default button is clicked, a new view model is created and the request function is called on that view model.

In the document ready function where you are defining what happens after the sales data is loaded, you have the following code which is what creates the view model that the html document is actually bound to:

```
    var vm = new viewModel();
    vm.salesdata(data.$values);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Nothing ever calls the request function on this view model.  I wonder if what you really want is to somehow bind the request function in this view model to the default button.

Comment: It would be helpful for those who down vote to include a comment about why they down voted.  I suspect simply because I rushed my answer and didn't ensure that it was clear with example code.  You are entitled to your opinions, but I would simply like to know why so that I can try to improve my answers in the future.

Comment: You're right. My bad. There were two answers to the question, GoTo's being very detailed and mentioning an important point with the click handler, while I found yours a bit generic. The question asker seems to need a bit more detail here. Therefore I upvoted GoTo's answer and downvoted yours. You've now edited and improved your answer so I've removed the downvote. My bad for not commenting.

Comment: I would downvote because this answer does not have HOW to update the original viewmodel, as I would say the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

I would try updating the viewmodel `salesdata` observable, by giving `context: self` and using the following `success` method:

```
self.request = function (uri) {
        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            context: self,
            data: [],
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            this.salesdata(data.$values);
        }
        });
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I can see you attached a click event with jQuery.
You should use knockout clck binding instead:

```
<button data-bind="click: clickEvent" value="1">Click me!</button>
```

And in the viewmodel

```
clickEvent: function (data, event) { 
    days = event.target.value;
    var uri = "/api/sales?days=" + days;     
    data.request(uri);
}
```

This way you can retrieve your viewmodel instead of creating a new one as you did with `new viewModel().request(uri);`

For more on click binding see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Answer (score 3):

Building slightly on the answer from @brader24 here:

In your update button's `click` event, you use this line of code:

`new viewModel().request(uri);`

What that is doing is creating a *new* `viewModel` (separate from the one that you already have instantiated and have applied bindings for) and filling it's observable array with data via your `request` function. It isn't affecting your original `viewModel` at all (the one that has it's bindings applied on the DOM!). So you won't see any errors, but you also won't see anything happening on the page because all you did was create a new `viewModel` in memory, fill it with data, and do nothing with it.

Try this code (everything in your `viewModel` function looks fine).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var vm = new viewModel(); // declare (and instantiate) your view model variable outside the context of the $.ajax call so that we have access to it in the click binding
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/sales",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
    }).done(function (data) {
        vm.salesdata(data.$values);
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    }).error(function (xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    });
    //Here i'm calling for ViewModel update
    $(".btn-default").click(function () {
        days = $(this).val();
        var uri = "/api/sales?days=" + days;     
        vm.request(uri); // don't use a new instance of a view model - use the one you have already instantiated
    });
});
```

Using a Knockout click binding instead of attaching a click event handler using jQuery is usually the recommended route, but it **is not necessary** - so your existing code (with the modifications above) should work fine. For more info on that, see [Using unobtrusive event handlers](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) in the Knockout docs

Comment: This is what I was talking about, but didn't describe clearly enough.  I updated my answer, but this answer explains it better and gives a solution which in my current inexperience I was not prepared to provide.

Comment: Guys, your suggestions look logically, but unfortunately it's not working.